# Unable to connect to angband Debian repo

Tags: debian, git

I tried the following:

```
$ git clone git://anonscm.debian.org/collab-maint/angband.git
Cloning into 'angband'...
fatal: unable to connect to anonscm.debian.org:
anonscm.debian.org[0: 194.177.211.202]: errno=Connection refused
```

I thought perhaps collab-maint might have moved to salsa.debian.org (the gitlab instance), but didn't find it there as well.

https://salsa.debian.org/explore/groups?filter=collab-maint

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong. FWIW I'm behind no proxy or firewall

Comment: Did you try to open these links in a web browser? they seem to be invalid ! ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated [at the old address](https://anonscm.debian.org/?p=collab-maint/angband.git;a=summary), Alioth has been discontinued. The Angband repository has not been migrated to Salsa, the replacement service, but you'll find an archive [here](https://alioth-archive.debian.org/git/collab-maint/angband.git.tar.xz).

I would suggest that you use `wget` to download the file

```
wget https://alioth-archive.debian.org/git/collab-maint/angband.git.tar.xz
```

then

```
tar -xJf angband.git.tar.xz
```

After that:

```
git clone /path/to/angband.git
```

Comment: didn't know there was a wget service there, thank you.